# Sending SMS AT-commands

Tags: c, serial-port, sms, at-command, modem

I have USB-Modem Huawei E171 with working SIM-card.

I'm trying to send SMS-message using Putty and have 500 error:

```
AT

OK

AT+CMGF=1

OK

AT+CMGS="+7923*******",145<enter>
>Hello<ctrl-z>

+CMS Error: 500
```

What can I do? I know that error 500 is unknown error. So I thought that somebody can have ideas about this thing. 
I checked the program, which called Huawei Modem, and it successfully sent my SMS. Feels like I didn't do something to initialize the modem.

Comment: I don't know a lot about this modem, but a short google search came up with the command `AT+CMGS="<PHONENUMBER>"<ENTER><MESSAGE><CTRL-Z>` without the `,`.

Comment: I tried this too, of course, nothing changed.

Comment: The documentation for Huawei modems says that the text mode is not supported. But other examples shows the command as: AT+CMGS="91234567"<CR>Sending text messages is easy.<Ctrl+z>

Comment: When `AT+CMGF=1` returns `OK` it means that text mode is both supported and selected.

Answer (score 2):

My modem is Quectel EG95 and below command is workable just for you reference.

```
AT+CMGF=1
AT+CSCS="GSM"
AT+CMGS="+7923*******" #The number you want to receive sms.
> This is a test msg   #Ctrl+Z to send or ESC to cancel.
```

Refer file is Quectel_EG9x_AT_Commands_Manual_V1.1.pdf